# Why does chrome shows address suggestion in one of the fields in my form?

Tags: html, google-chrome

My form has a lot of text fields, and auto fill behaves normally except one, with "route" as the name. Chrome thinks it is an address field.

How can I make the auto fill behaves as normal, but not showing my address there?

The following screenshots demonstrate the problem. The table header is the same as the form input name.

[image: Problematic field]
[image: Normal field]

Comment: It's just a plain `<input type="text" />` field?

Comment: <input id="route" name="route" type="text" maxlength="255" />

Comment: I went through a similar issue the past few days. In my case what was causing that strange behavior was a pdf viewer (pdfjs). As soon as I moved the viewer outside of the form element, the issue disappeared. Loading the viewer inside an iframe also solved it. I don't know the root cause but it was definitely that.

Answer (score 2):

In the absence of any specific `autocomplete` attribute, Chrome will use heuristics to try and figure out what kind of input it should accept. This can be based on the `name` attribute, `<labels>` etc.

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete) for a list of accepted `autocomplete` attributes and see if any applies to your situation. If not, use `autocomplete="off"` to disable autocompletion.